# I want to fetch Year from x.CreatedDate how to do that?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

```
_dbEntities.Salaries.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == EmployeeID && x.MonthID == MonthID && x.CreatedDate == Year).SingleOrDefault();
```

I want to fetch Year from x.CreatedDate how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just check the `Year` property of `DateTime` object. And it must work:

```
   _dbEntities.Salaries.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == EmployeeID && 
                                   x.MonthID == MonthID && 
                                   x.CreatedDate.Year == Year)
                       .SingleOrDefault();
```

If this column is nullable, then you must change it as : `x.CreatedDate.Value.Year == Year`

I have just checked it in `LinqToEntity` against MS Sql Server database and it works fine.

***P.S:*** I think they have removed `EntityFunctions.Year()` and replaced it with this.

Answer (score 0):

It may hit performance to convert a database field value before comparing it, because it disables any indexes on this field (the expression is not [*sargeable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)). So while Farhad's solution is probably OK (because you also filter on other highly selective fields), and worth accepting, it *may* be better to do

```
var lowerBound = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
var upperBound = new DateTime(year + 1, 1, 1);

_dbEntities.Salaries
           .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == EmployeeID 
                    && x.MonthID == MonthID 
                    && x.CreatedDate >= lowerBound)
                    && x.CreatedDate < upperBound)
            .SingleOrDefault();
```